# WPF - Usar ItemsControl dentro de ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf

Estoy teniendo un problema un tanto extraño. Para empezar tengo estas dos clases:

```
public class Server
{
    public Guid id { get; set; }
    public string descripcion { get; set; }
    public string nombre { get; set; }
    public List<PathSync> carpetas { get; set; }
}

public class PathSync
{
    public Guid id { get; set; }
    public string origen { get; set; }
    public string destino { get; set; }
    public int tipocopia { get; set; }
}
```

En mi aplicación creo una lista de objetos Server y los inicializo, creando también la lista de objetos PathSync dentro de cada objeto. Una vez tengo esta lista creada, inicializo el `ItemsControls` con **`collapsedPanelItem.ItemsSource = lista`**.

Despues, en mi aplicación WPF, en la vista, tengo el siguiente bloque:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="collapsedPanelItem">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Expander Header="{Binding nombre}">
                <StackPanel Margin="10" Orientation="Vertical">
                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding descripcion}" />
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding carpetas}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                    <Label Content="{Binding origen}" />
                                    <Label Content="{Binding destino}" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </StackPanel>
            </Expander>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Al ejecutar mi aplicación me aparece la lista de desplegables mostrando el nombre y, al desplegarlo, se ve el label de dentro con la descripción, pero el segundo `ItemsControl` no muestra el listado de carpetas.

¿Alguien sabe que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Puedes confirmarnos que `carpetas` si contiene valor? Acabo de hacer la prueba y me funciono perfectamente.

Comment: Lo validé justo antes de poner esto aquí y tiene valores. He incluido la linea `collapsedPanelItem.Items.Refresh()` y con eso ya si me pinta correctamente los datos del segundo `ItemsControl`.

Comment: Se que es un poco tarde pero hice la prueba y me funciono perfectamente. Pudieras un proyecto de prueba a mi correo einersantanar@gmail.com para darle una mirada?

Comment: @Einer creo que es mejor mantener la conversación aqui en SOes. Si quieres , puedo crear una sala para que hableis. Ahi la gente puede entrar para aportar o para informarse de ese caso. Las preguntas/respuestas del sitio no ayudan solo al que formuló el problema si no a futuros users con problemas similares. Y recuerda que si habeis llegado a una solución ya, publicarla como respuesta 
 :P Un saludo

Comment: Por curiosidad hermano, ¿Lograste solucionarlo?

Comment: Si, tenia razon @Einer, habia un momento en el que el valor de la variable se perdia y por eso no me pintaba los datos.

Answer (score 1):

Te falta colocar el tipo de dato en tu DataTemplate el x:Type se conforma por dos partes (referencia xlmns : nombre de clase):

Debes hacer referencia en tu namespace de tu UserControl, Page o lo que sea que estés usando, estas lineas se encuentran en la parte inicial de tu archivo xaml:

Ejemplo:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Project.ServerElements"
```

una vez referenciado, lo colocas en tu DataTemplate así:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="collapsedPanelItem">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Server}">
            <Expander Header="{Binding nombre}">
                <StackPanel Margin="10" Orientation="Vertical">
                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding descripcion}" />
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding carpetas}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                    <Label Content="{Binding origen}" />
                                    <Label Content="{Binding destino}" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </StackPanel>
            </Expander>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Espero que te sirva.

Saludos